# Same formula - different result. How does it work?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

On those pictures you can see the same info and formulas but different result. It appears just randomly. It's just replacing numbers with date. Idk what is it and how to fix it :(
Oh, and the formula itself:
`=B21*F21-B21*C21-(D21*B21)`
Here's the sheet:
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H3rrGK7uIfwbMI2Pg27IHxY_JPKr4sKDqa6HWdJ0iEw/edit?usp=sharing`

1. [Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN1hZ.png)
2. [Uncorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZgvJ.png)
3. [Here's the result of inserting the formula to the other columns and rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANXj5.png)

1. I tried to write it by hand again;
2. I tried to change numbers in the sections and in the formula
3. I tried to copy this formula to another columns

Comment: Select cell or whole column. Format -> Number -> Number

Answer (score 0):

*The issue here in this instance seems to be the value in `Cell_C23` **13.09** is taken for date automatically by the sheet. As per your sheet locale you need to enter the value as **13,09***

*I'd suggest to clear the `C23` cell and enter the value freshly (**13,09***) and your calculation(s) should be good to go...*

[image]